# Site Feed doesnt work on Blank Site

Tags: 2013, newsfeed

If I create a **team site** and add a site feed to it, it works. It shows the title: Newsfeed, and input box and the line that says "It's pretty quiet here. *Invite* more people to the site."

When I create a **blank site** and add a site feed to it, it shows the title and the line of text without an input box.

I'm wondering why that is. I've invited myself, confirmed that the site is shared with me, but still no ability to post probably pictures of my cat or thoughts I just had that no one cares about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you activated the News (or is it Site) Feed feature? It is a site scoped feature.

I know there has been problems with activating this one from PowerShell (the user would need to have very high permissions), but it works as it should when done from the GUI.

If it shows up as already activated, try to deactivate it and then activate it again.